# How change python logging to display time passed from when the script execution started?

Tags: python, logging

I want to modify the python logging to log the time elapsed from when the script started (or when the logging module was initialized).

```
000:00 DEBUG bla bla
000:01 ERROR wow! ... this is measured in minutes:seconds
```

I found the `relativeCreated` variable in the logging module, but this is givving me millisecond accuracy which would only spam the logs, making harder to see where the time goes or how log it took to run.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why?  Why not just log when the program starts?  Without the full date your log will lose some context.  Format of logging messages can be set by creating a format string:  `FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s  %(message)s';logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)`

Comment: Vinay's answer addresses your question quite well - don't you want to accept it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `logging.Formatter` subclass which gets the `relativeCreated` from the `LogRecord` passed to its `format` method, format it as mins:secs and output it in the format string e.g. using a different placeholder in the format string, such as `%(adjustedTime)s`:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.adjustedTime = format_as_mins_and_secs(record.relativeCreated)
        return super(MyFormatter, self).format(record)
```

where you can define `format_as_mins_and_secs` to return the formatted relative time.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure you can do this using the `logging` python module (I could be wrong).

If you need the run-time of the application, though, I would say you should capture the time at application start in a variable (using the `time` module). Once the time has been captured, you can then pass that variable to the logger to calculate the difference when hitting an error.

Answer (score -3):

First that pops up in my mind .

1. Calculate time delta  between time script started and time that  is now.
2. Use datetime module for that (do calc to epoh secs and back to timestamp) .
3. Insert results by  loggin module into  message section.

I do not  put  any code for now to inspire you to read more about modules mentioned ).