# Python logging time since start of program

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the logging module to create loggers and output data. Instead of using `$(asctime)s` in `logging.Formatter`, is there a good way to log the timestamp relative to the creation of the logger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How change python logging to display time passed from when the script execution started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639387/how-change-python-logging-to-display-time-passed-from-when-the-script-execution)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could write your own formatter:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import logging
import time

class ElapsedFormatter():

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def format(self, record):
        elapsed_seconds = record.created - self.start_time
        #using timedelta here for convenient default formatting
        elapsed = timedelta(seconds = elapsed_seconds)
        return "{} {}".format(elapsed, record.getMessage())

#add custom formatter to root logger for simple demonstration
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(ElapsedFormatter())
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)

log = logging.getLogger('test')
log.error("Message 1")

time.sleep(5)

log.error("Message 2")
```

Your question refers to the elapsed time from the 'start of program' as well as 'creation of logger' which could mean different things.

This will measure the time elapsed from the creation of `CustomFormatter` which you could do close to the start of the program or when a logger is created.

Comment: Thx for this tip. I used time.clock() instead of timedelta. Dunno if there are any tradeoffs with doing that, but calculations are a little simpler.

Answer (score 32):

Using [`%(relativeCreated)d`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) field in a conventional `Formatter` format string will display the milliseconds elapsed since the `logging` module was loaded. While milliseconds might not be what you want, there's no additional coding required.

Answer (score 4):

I liked Franky1's answer but I didn't want to lose *%(asctime)s* style in the log format. Here's a solution that adds a *%(delta)s* style.

```
import datetime
import logging
import time

class DeltaTimeFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        duration = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(record.relativeCreated / 1000)
        record.delta = duration.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        return super().format(record)

# add custom formatter to root logger
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
LOGFORMAT = '+%(delta)s - %(asctime)s - %(levelname)-9s: %(message)s'
fmt = DeltaTimeFormatter(LOGFORMAT)
handler.setFormatter(fmt)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# test of the logger output
logger.error('Test')
for sleep in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
    time.sleep(sleep)
    logger.error('logging')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own solution based on some stackoverflow ideas.
It is a subclass of `logging.Formatter`

```py
import datetime
import logging
import time

# subclass of logging.Formatter
class RuntimeFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_time = time.time()
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        duration = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(record.created - self.start_time)
        elapsed = duration.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        return "{}".format(elapsed)

# add custom formatter to root logger
LOGFORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-9s: %(message)s'
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
fmt = RuntimeFormatter(LOGFORMAT)
handler.setFormatter(fmt)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# test of the logger output
logger.error('Test')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the above code of formatter to work as a filter. This is better because you can now use existing formatting of logger and see the elapsed time as part of the existing logging statement; otherwise, formatter prints on a different line and you can't leverage existing formatting functionality

```
from datetime import timedelta
import logging
import time


class ElapsedFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
    
    def filter(self, record):
   
        elapsed_seconds = record.created - self.start_time
        #using timedelta here for convenient default formatting
        elapsed = timedelta(seconds = elapsed_seconds)
        record.elapsed=elapsed
        return True


logging.basicConfig(
                level=logging.INFO,
                format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s line %(lineno)d  %(message)s  Elapsed: %(elapsed)s",
                datefmt="%H:%M:%S")


log = logging.getLogger('test')
f = ElapsedFilter()
log.addFilter(f)
log.error("Message 1")

time.sleep(5)

log.error("Message 2")
time.sleep(2)
log.info("Message 3")
```

Output of this program:

```
17:59:53 ERROR test line 36  Message 1  Elapsed: 0:00:00.000029
17:59:58 ERROR test line 40  Message 2  Elapsed: 0:00:05.002165
18:00:00 INFO test line 42  Message 3  Elapsed: 0:00:07.004427
```