# Python logger with adjusted timestamp?

Tags: python, windows, time

We've got two Windows machines that are talking back and forth, the problem is that the two machines haven't always had their system times set to the same values which makes it hard to figure out what happened when looking at the log files.

The primary machine is on the Internet so we call his timestamp "correct", and we can send his timestamp over the LAN so the secondary machine knows the primary machine's timestamp, but the program on the secondary machine doesn't have the necessary authorization to update its Windows system time.

Is there any way to set the Python logger so the timestamp that gets written to the secondary machine's log is different from the Windows system timestamp?  That is, if the secondary machine thinks it's 12:00:00 but the primary machine says it's actually 12:00:05, can the Python logger on the secondary machine be set so it adds 5 seconds to the Window system time when generating its timestamp?

Comment: Seems kind of unlikely, without looking at the source code I'd guess it just asks for the current time from Windows and uses it directly.

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194864/python-logging-time-since-start-of-program give you some ideas to tackle the problem?