# Python logging time since start in seconds

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I would like to add the number of seconds my program is up to my logging output.

I've found `relativeCreated` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) but it will give me the milliseconds, e.g. this:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='{relativeCreated:8.0f}ms {levelname:s} {message:s}', style="{")
```

Results in

```
4081ms INFO my message
6012ms INFO another message
```

But as I expect the running times to be in the hours, I would prefer.

```
4s INFO my message
6s INFO another message
```

I tried

```
logging.basicConfig(format='{relativeCreated / 1000:4.0f}s {levelname:s} {message:s}', style="{")
```

but this results in

```
KeyError: 'relativeCreated / 1000'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How change python logging to display time passed from when the script execution started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639387/how-change-python-logging-to-display-time-passed-from-when-the-script-execution)

Comment: Another similar question: [Python logging time since start of program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25194864/427158)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass [logging.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) to modify `relativeCreated`:

```py
import logging
import time

class RelativeSeconds(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.relativeCreated = record.relativeCreated // 1000
        return super().format(record)

formatter = RelativeSeconds("%(relativeCreated)ds %(levelname)s %(message)s")

logging.basicConfig()
logging.root.handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)

logging.error("Test 1")
time.sleep(2)
logging.error("Test 2")
```

Prints:

```py
0s ERROR Test 1
2s ERROR Test 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`logging.getLogRecordFactory()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLogRecordFactory) to add attributes to all [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord).

In the code below, a new attribute called `uptime` is added to each LogRecord. `uptime` is just `relativeCreated` divided by 1000:

```
old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.uptime = record.relativeCreated/1000
    return record

logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)
```

Then you can use that attribute in your formatter as

```
%(uptime)d %(levelname)s %(message)s
```

A complete example here:

```
import logging.config
import time
import random


logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "formatters": {
            "default": {
                "format": "%(uptime)07.3f %(uptime)03d %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s",
            }
        },
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "formatter": "default",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
            }
        },
        'root': {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
    }
)


old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.uptime = record.relativeCreated/1000
    return record

logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2.5))
    log.debug('iteration %d', i)
```

which will produce

```
002.308 002 DEBUG    __main__        iteration 0
003.089 003 DEBUG    __main__        iteration 1
005.393 005 DEBUG    __main__        iteration 2
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
........
print (str(time.time() - start_time) + ' INFO my message')
```

It should return time in [s]

Comment: Thanks, I would like to keep using the logging module as it allows to filter for logging level, write to file / stdout separately etc.